# Update model with data from "different" view - MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

How can I add a new object item to a Main Views model that has been created in a different model?

I am trying to add a new item to a list which is contained in my main view model.

Before adding this item, I need info about the properties for this item, so I use a view strongly tied to a model which contains necessary input fields.  I have made the model for this view a wrapper style which contains two objects.  The main view's model as well as a model for the specific item.

**MODEL**

```
public class MDTCompletedJobM : BaseM
{
...
public MDTPartMList PartsList { get; set; }
...
}


public class MDTAddPartM
{
    public MDTPartM Part { get; set; }
    public MDTCompletedJobM CompletedJobM { get; set; }
    public List<string> PartTypes { get; set; }

    public MDTAddPartM()
    {
        Part = new MDTPartM();
        PartTypes = (List<string>)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("MTDataPartTypeList");
    }
}
```

so when the view is called from my controller, I assign my mains views model to this model and pass it in.  From the "Add Part" view, I then use an Ajax post call to actually add the part to this List (CompletedJobM.PartsList).

This works fine except I now don't know how to get my main view to be aware in it's model that there is an extra Item in it's list.  This new item is not "stored" anywhere after it's been added to the model list, so I can't reload the main view model.  My Ajax post is:

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            url: '@Url.Action("AddPart", "Jobs")', //$(this).attr("action"),
            data: $.toJSON(result),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (data) {

                $("#progressdiv").html();

                var isValid = $(data).find(".validation-summary-errors").length == 0;

                if (isValid) {
                    var pwindow = $("#Window").data("tWindow");
                    pwindow.close();
                    $('.page').html(data); <- what to do here?
                }
                else {

                    $("#resultDiv").html(data);
                }
            },

            beforeSend: function () {
                $("#progressdiv").html('<image src=@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/ajax-loader.gif") alt="Loading, please wait" />');
            },

            error: function (xhtr, e) {
                $("#progressdiv").html();
                alert(xhtr.responseText);
            }
        });
```

Currently (since I'm returning a View) I tried just assigning the returned HTML to a  tag of the main view, but that caused issues with overlapping displays and further processing issues with button clicks and so forth.

My question is at the top line?  Maybe I've gone about it all wrong?

Thanks

**EDIT**

Ok, let me rephrase this question slightly.  Ignore my actual code.  What *principles* or general concept would someone use to update a model of one View (in this case a list) with the model from a different view (entry form), such that when refreshing the Main View it contains the information from the 2nd view *bearing in mind that after the second view has been updated/posted, it's not written to a DB or anywhere.  It's effectively in memory*.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up doing was storing my Model in the Session object and retrieved it and used that while re-rendering the page.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand you correctly:

1. Your main view has a model which has a `PartsList`
2. Your "Add Part" view makes an ajax request to add a new item to the `PartsList` (but doesn't store it in a DB... so what is it doing?)
3. Nothing is stored in a DB

I think the problem here is the design. How does the main view originally get it's list of parts? Or does it start off empty and parts are added using "Add part"?

To be honest I see 2 options:

1. Redesign your application so that the main view reads its `PartsList` from a DB and "Add Part" adds items to the DB. This way, after your ajax call you can refresh the main view.
2. Keep state client-side: this can be a hidden input that you store your list of parts as a comma separated string and use some javascript to keep the add parts and main view in sync. Messy but doable.

I'm heavily leaning towards #1.

Comment: 1. Correct
2. Correct (mostly)
3. Incorrect

Data is initially stored in a DB - the parts list at the point may be empty or have items in it.

When I want to add a new part to this list, I call my 2nd View to provide inputs about this part (Description, Cost, Type is all. ie 3 fields).  My main view displays a current list of these parts.  After the user has clicked OK on the "Add" view, I want my main to display in it's list this new part.  I can't store the part directly in the DB from the "Add" view because other processing needs to take place based on the Main view.  HTH